# Docker volume binding: Base image vs derivative image

Tags: docker

It looks like any **volume binding** (`-v`) used when you `run` a base image will not be retained in the derived image that you commit, and the volume binding option has to be passed each time you `run` the derived image.

**Example:**

---

```
docker run -it -v /opt/hostappsdir:/apps ubuntu
```

make changes in the container (named: *john_doe*) and commit to a new image (*local/test*)

```
docker commit john_doe local/test
```

Then, this does not list the files in the host directory `/opt/hostappsdir`

```
docker run --rm local/test ls /apps
```

but this one does it

```
docker run --rm -v /opt/hostappsdir:/apps local/test ls /apps
```

---

Is there any way I can avoid passing the volume binding option each time?

Comment: It would be helpful if the person who downvoted my question explains what's wrong with it.

Comment: Ok. Corrected the syntax error in the `commit` command. Waiting for an answer...

Comment: I also have no idea why this question has been down voted - it a legitimate controversy and thus a valid question for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volumes are by definition not part of the layers of the container and thus will not be part of the layers you commit when creating a Image from the container.

If you like to e.g. add your specific configuration, add some extensions, add some packages, you should always derive from the base image, never just "commit" arbitrary, not formalised changes.

Create a Dockerfile with

```
from <baseimage>
COPY yourconfig /etc/somewhere
COPY yourasset /var/www

RUN sed ... \ // change some configuration
  && apt-get update && apt-get install curl // some packages
```

Hint: I do myself not like the idea of "commiting changes a containers to an image" - that is risky, does not produce the same result every time and more over, does not formalise what you actually changed. You will have hard times .e.g. updating your image due to updates of the base image, since you do not know, what you have done before that - and even if you have written it down, its a lot of effort to do that again, again and again.

Comment: Thanks. The first line in your response is the answer I wanted. The changes I meant are for adding additional apt packages. Code changes will only be done on the host directory bind to the container.

Comment: I was probably living under a rock or something, but I just learned about `docker-compose`... Wow! This is the kind of thing I was expecting and docker-compose made all the bash scripts I wrote totally redundant!