# How to update code in a docker container?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I've set up a docker django container and made its image using build using tutorial [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/). The tutorial shows how to make a basic django application and mounts the application to ***"/code"***, which as I understand, is contained in a data-volume.

However I want to understand that how will I be able to update and develop this code, and be able to ship/deploy it. Since when I make a commit, it's doesn't take account any changes in the code, since it's a part of the data volume.

Is there any way I can make the django code a part of the image, or update the image with the updated code?

Comment: You simply add the Python source code into a container which has appropriate python dependencies installed. And keep the `ENTRYPOINT` of that container to `["python", "/path/to/my.py"]`. Building the docker image is something to be done by your CI system based on rules like only on tags or only from master and so on.

Comment: How do I add the source code in the container and not in the data volume?

Comment: General workflows have a separate `Dockerfile.development` and `Dockerfile` (for production). Volume is in the development but the production dockerfile doesn't have a volume instruction (in your case it is not required). Just simply do a `ADD . /code`. No volumes.

Answer (score 11):

In my experience Docker serves two purposes:

1. To be able to develop code in a containerized environment. This is very useful as I am now able to get new developers on my team ready to work in about 5 mins Previously, this could have taken anywhere from an hour to several hours for misc issues, especially on older projects.
2. To be able to package an application in a containerized environment. This is also a great time saver as the only requirement for the environment is to have Docker installed.

When you are developing your code you should mount the source/volume so that your changes are always reflected inside the container. When you want to package an app for deployment you should `COPY` the source into the container and package it appropriately.

Here is a docker-compose file I use to (1) build an image to develop against, (2) develop my code, and (3) ship it (I'm using spring boot):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  dev:
    image: '${MVN_BUILDER}'
    container_name: '${CONTAINER_NAME}'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - './src:/build/src'
      - './db:/build/db'
      - './target:/build/target'
      - './logs:/build/logs'
    command: 'mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xmx512m" -Dmaven.test.skip=true'
  deploy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-Deploy
      args:
        MVN_BUILDER: '${MVN_BUILDER}'
    image: '${DEPLOYMENT_IMAGE}'
    container_name: '${CONTAINER_NAME}'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  maven:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: '${MVN_BUILDER}'
    container_name: '${CONTAINER_NAME}'
```

1. I would run `docker-compose build maven` to build my base image. This is needed so that when I run my code in a container all the dependencies are installed in the image. The Dockerfile for this essentially copies to `pom.xml` into the image and downloads the dependencies needed for the app. Note this would need to be performed anytime dependencies change. Here is the Dockerfile to build that image that is referenced in the `maven` service:

```
### BUILD a maven builder. This will contain all mvn dependencies and act as an abstraction for all mvn goals
FROM maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-alpine as builder

#Copy Custom Maven settings
#COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/

# create app folder for sources
RUN mkdir -p /build
RUN mkdir -p /build/logs

# The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.
WORKDIR /build
COPY pom.xml /build
#Download all required dependencies into one layer
RUN mvn -B dependency:go-offline dependency:resolve-plugins
RUN mvn clean install
```

2. Next, I would run `docker-compose up dev` to start my `dev` service and begin to develop my application. This service mounts my code into the container and uses Maven to start a spring boot application. Anytime I change the code spring boot restarts the server and my changes are reflected.
3. Finally, once I am happy with my application I build an image that has my application packaged for deployment using `docker-compose build deploy`. I use a two-stage build process to first copy the source into a container and package it for deployment as a `Jar` then that `Jar` is put into the 2nd stage where I can simply run `java -jar build/app.jar` (in the container) to start my application and the first stage is removed. That's It! Now you can deploy this latest image anywhere Docker is installed.

Here is what that last Dockerfile (Dockerfile-Deploy) looks like:

```
ARG MVN_BUILDER
### Stage 1 - BUILD image
FROM $MVN_BUILDER as builder
COPY src /build/src
RUN mvn clean package -PLOCAL

### Stage 2 - Deploy Jar
FROM openjdk:8
RUN mkdir -p /build
COPY --from=builder /build/target/*.jar /build/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080  
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","build/app.jar"]
```

Here the `.env` file in the same directory as the `docker-compose` file. I use it to abstract image/container names and simply bump up the version number in one place when a new image is needed.

```
MVN_BUILDER=some/maven/builder:0.1
DEPLOYMENT_IMAGE=some/deployment/spring:0.1
CONTAINER_NAME=spring-container
CONTAINER_NAME_DEBUG=spring-container-debug
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it's too late to answer your question, however, it might be beneficial for others who reach out.

The tutorial you mentioned is a bit tricky to use for the first-timers, so, I change the structure a little bit. I assume that you have a docker registry account (like Dockerhub) for the purpose of publishing the images to. This is required if you want to access the image on a remote host (you can copy the actual image file but is not recommended).

### creating a project

Assume that you are going to create a website with Django and dockerize it, first, you do:

```
django-admin startproject samplesite
```

It creates a directory `samplesite` that includes the following (I added requirements.txt):

```
db.sqlite3  manage.py  requirements.txt  samplesite
```

### adding Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

For the `Dockerfile`, as you can see, nothing is changed compared to the `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

However for the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    image: yourUserNameOnDockerHub/mywebsite:0.1  # this line is added
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    #volumes:
    #  - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`docker-compose.yml` is also almost identical to the one mentioned in the tutorial, with volume commented and one line added `image: mywebsite:0.1`. This line allows us to track the built image and deploy it whenever we want. The volume mounting **is not** related to the code you write and was put there to *take out* the dynamic content that is changed by Django (sqlite, uploaded files, etc.).

### build and run

If you run `docker-compose up` the first time everything works fine, however, because of the new line added, when you change the code after the first time, the changes will not reflect in the container that runs. This is because upon each `docker-compose up`, compose will look for `mywebsite:0.1` (that already exists) and does not build a new image and creates a container based on the old one. As we need that image name and tag to publish/deploy our image, we need to instead use:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

***It will re-build an image with the changes reflected***. Every time you make some changes, run it and a new fresh image is created that can be seen with (note that although the name and tag remain unchanged, change in image id shows that this is a new image):

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
yourUserNameOnDockerHub/mywebsite            0.1                 033c9d2bfac0        7 seconds ago       974MB
```

### publishing and deployment

If you have set up an account on Dockerhub (or any other registry) you can publish the image for later use or deployment on a remote server:

```
docker push yourUserNameOnDockerHub/mywebsite:01
```

If you want to deploy it on a remote host and want to use docker-compose again, Just change the `docker-compose.yml` to:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    image: yourUserNameOnDockerHub/mywebsite:0.1 
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    #volumes:
    #  - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Note that the `build: .` line is removed (as we are going to run it only). When developing locally, whenever you run `docker-compose up --build` a new image will be created and tagged and a container based on that will run in the compose stack. If you thought that you are happy with the changes, you follow the publishing step to make it live on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In step 9 of the [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) you set a volume. This volume will link your current directory and your container `/code` directory. In other words, they will be the same.

So any updates to your local files will change the files in your container as well. Remember that you will need to restart your app so the changes can take place.

Before you deploy your image, you will need to create a second docker compose file. This file will remove the volume so the code will stay inside the container and won't change from outside. You can follow the steps provided in [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/).

Comment: When I change files in /code, they show up on the local web app, but when I push the container image, and deploy it, it doesn't contain the changes.

Comment: I think that the volume option might be the problem. When you push your container and run it, the volume will still  work but not with your local files anymore. Be sure to update the code where you are deploying.

Another alternative would be to remove the volume. That way you would need to rebuild you image every time you update your code.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. How do I update the code where I am deploying?

Comment: Where are you deploying to? VPS? Cloud?

Comment: First thing you need to do when you are deploying is to _Remove any volume bindings for application code, so that code stays inside the container and can't be changed from outside_.
You can follow this [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/) for doing so. 

I'll update my answer based on that.

Comment: but the code exists as a part of the volume only! How do I make it ***stay*** inside the container.

Comment: You are already doing that on your Dockerfile on this line: `ADD . /code/`. You are copying everything from your current directory to /code inside the container. This happens when you build your image. The volume thing happens only when you run the container.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update an image, lets say due to your application code changes, you use `COPY` during your image-build, so in the `Dockerfile` you do something like

```
COPY /you/code/on/the/host /var/www
```

Also see my answer about "volumes" and image-building https://stackoverflow.com/a/39314602/3625317 to clarify why your code is missing in the build

Comment: thanks for taking the time. this worked a lot for me :)